# Unity C# getting a variable from another script on the same GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

So I got the default FPSController as my GameObject.

I added a script called Controller with a bool called holding which allows me to pick up an object. 
Now I want to add an if statement to the FirstPersonController script in which I can't run if hold is true. Therefore I need the bool hold in my FPScontroller script.

I tried diffrent ways to do it but every time I use
`.GetComponent<Controller>`

I get an error saying that Controller can not be found.

The clas from Controller is public as well as the bool hold. 
They are both on the same Object.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like everything seems to be fine.

What happens when in your FPSController you write

```
Controller controller = transform.GetComponent<Controller>();
```

Is controller null? Or do you get a null reference exception?

Comment: Try reimporting your Controller script. Right click on it and click reimport. Also see if there is no other script of the same name in your project

Comment: did. changed nothing. It looks like he just doesnt find the controller.cs but how could i make him find it else than puting both on the same GameObject and making both public?

Comment: You can put it on any GameObject and either access it publicly via inspector or GameObject.Find("Gameobjectname").GetComponent<Controller>()

Comment: GameObject.Find("Gameobjectname").GetComponent<Controller>()  has <Controller> red underlined. Saying that Controller could not be found

Comment: Please verify if there is a Controller script in your project. Also run the project and see if you get an error. Are you using visual studio?

Comment: [link]http://prntscr.com/lsnh2g

this is my project and the controller script works fine. I dont get any errors at the start of the project and yes i use visual studio

Comment: Got it fixed

using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;

was missing in the controller script.

Answer (score 0):

your trying to get the "controller" as a child of the script your in. try :

```
this.GameObject.GetComponent<Controller>
```

it might be:

```
 this.gameObject.GetComponent<Controller>
```

but one of those will fix your problem